The number of ‘review invitations accepted' reduced?
I have a paper submission to Elsevier. It's a revised re-submission after one round of review. I got review feedback from 2 reviewers in the first round review. So for our re-submission I suspect the editor sent our revisions to the original 2 reviewers.
The weird thing is that the number in the red circle used to be 2 since 03/10/2024, both reviewers accepted to review but one of them has not returned his/her feedback within 2 months. Today (05/10/2024) the number in the red circle reduced to 1. Can anyone please explain what is going on? Does the reviewer reject the review invitation after accepting it or the editor just disallow the reviewer to review any more?


When something that needs your attention happens, the editor will contact you. There's no useful purpose in consulting the bones or interpreting status changes as if they are Tarot cards.

I imagine the reviewer completed their review, hence "Reviews completed" went from 0 to 1, and "Review invitations accepted" dropped from 2 to 1.

"Review invitations accepted" remains even if someone completes review.
